# Question about $e^{\frac{-itA}{\hbar}}(\hat{Q}+ \hat{P})e^{\frac{itA}{\hbar}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, semigroup-of-operators

This arises in the context of trying to rigorously understand quantum dynamics but it's a functional analysis issue. For simplicity suppose we are in dimension $1$.

> Let $\hat{Q}$ be the operator that's multiplication by $x$ and $\hat{P} = \frac{h}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$. Suppose $A$ is a denseley defined self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and that $$e^{\frac{-itA}{\hbar}}(\hat{Q}+ \hat{P})e^{\frac{itA}{\hbar}} = a\hat{Q} + b\hat{P}$$
>   where $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$

The author then says it follows from "exponentiation" that 
$$e^{\frac{-itA}{\hbar}}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(\hat{Q}+ \hat{P})}e^{\frac{itA}{\hbar}} = e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(a\hat{Q} + b\hat{P})}$$
I can't think of a rigorous explanation for what exponentiation means and why the first identity implies the second. In particular I'm uncomfortable with the fact that conjugating by a unitary operator goes through the exponentiation. I'm assuming this is a functional calculus thing. I was wondering if anyone knew of a rigorous explanation for this.

Comment: In most case this should be enough : let $D(A)\subset L^2$ be a dense subspace and $A$ be self-adjoint $D(A) \to L^2$
(that is for $f,g \in D(A)$, $\langle Af,g \rangle = \langle f, Ag \rangle$) and $(A-cI)^{-1}$ be compact for some $c$, then the SVD gives $(A-cI)^{-1} f= \sum_n \lambda_n \langle f,\phi_n \rangle \phi_n$, 
$A f= \sum_n (\lambda_n^{-1}+c) \langle f,\phi_n \rangle \phi_n$ where $\lambda_n^{-1}+c$ are real and $e^{i t A} f = \sum_n e^{it(\lambda_n^{-1}+c)} \langle f,\phi_n \rangle \phi_n$ is well-defined and unitary $L^2 \to L^2$

Comment: What do you mean by SVD?

Comment: @J.B.R Who is the author? or better, what book is it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the level of rigor you need. But in physics this identity is normally motivated as follows (let me set $h=1$ for readability):
$$
U = e^{it A}\;\Longrightarrow\; U U^{\dagger}  = \mathbb{1}\,.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
U^\dagger\, e^{i(\hat{Q}+\hat{P})} U &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty U^\dagger\, \frac{i^n}{n!}(\hat{Q}+\hat{P})^n \,U \\&=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n!}\, U^\dagger\, (\hat{Q}+\hat{P})\,UU^\dagger (\hat{Q}+\hat{P}) \cdots U U^\dagger (\hat{Q}+\hat{P}) \,U \\&
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n!}\, \big(U^\dagger\, (\hat{Q}+\hat{P})\,U\big)^n = \\&=
e^{i \,U^\dagger\, (\hat{Q}+\hat{P})\,U}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
From which the desired identity follows. In the second line I simply inserted $\mathbb{1}$ in between each factor in the form of $UU^\dagger$.

I guess one should also motivate that the exponential of the operator $\hat{Q} + \hat{P}$ is well defined as a power series. For the operator $\hat{Q}$ alone this is just multiplication by $e^x$ and it clearly matches the sum $\sum_n x^n/n!$. For $\hat{P}$ the convergence of the exponential is the same as the convergence for the Taylor expansion
$$
e^{ia\hat{P}} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x) = f(x+a)\,.
$$
Assuming $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In order to exponentiate $\hat{Q} + \hat{P}$ you may use [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula). 
$$
e^{\hat{Q}}e^{\hat{P}} = e^{\hat{Q}+\hat{P} + \frac12 i}\,,
$$
where I used $[\hat{Q},\hat{P}] = i \mathbb{1}$ and the fact that all other terms are commutators with $\mathbb{1}$ which vanish.

Comment: Right, this is how I typically think about these things, but I'm not sure how to make sense of this formal series mathematically

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups